# IE9 jQuery $ error

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I have created a jQuery script to allow my background cloud animation to run in IE since I use the CSS3 :after and :before pseudos and keyframes for all other browsers. It runs in all browsers except, of course IE9. For some reason it throughs up an error on the first `$` on line 8. I have searched online for an answer but so far I have found nothing, I have also tried forcing IE to revert to using IE8 compatibility mode, to see if it would work but that produced the same error. Has anyone else had the same error and know how to fix it? Even if I totally remove the whole line `$(init);` the error just moves to line 9 instead. [image: This is the error message that is produced while using the IE debugging.]

Here is the URL to my site to have a look for yourself, http://cafe.cic.hull.ac.uk/~405851/

Comment: Please post the actual code instead of a picture of the code.

Comment: Wow, your site uses 36%(!) of my CPU (i5-2500). You might want to fix that.

Comment: That error suggests jQuery did not load or is loaded after the line itself

Comment: @andbeyond, if that were the case, you'd see the same error in other browsers.

Comment: @Sparky: I almost guarantee it *is* the case, and something else specific to IE is causing the jQuery file to load slower or not load at all.

Comment: Maybe there is a syntax error that avoid IE to load correctly your jQuery. Firefox and other webkit have a better behaviour regading bad tag and this kind of problem (Missing closing tag, missing properties, a comma that should not be here.. etc). That could explain that is running fine on other browser.

Comment: @andbeyond, if you can almost guarantee it, then post the answer.  user1073122, you're right, IE is very sensitive to bad syntax, however, the 'trailing comma of death' will not affect IE 9.

Comment: @andbeyond, what are you whining about?  I never said you were wrong or I would have down-voted your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're loading `clouds.js` before loading jQuery. Move the <script> tag that links to clouds.js *after* both jQuery and jQueryUI and your problem should be solved.

Comment: Of course stupid mistake, thank you for pointing it out.